# Report on a Google Analytics custom dimension on landing page only

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I have a large website and am using content grouping to group pages by template type.

On our country pages (template is `country`), we show a lead image chosen randomly from a small set.

We'd like to look at user engagement by lead image for users landing on a country page, so we can investigate if certain types of image lead to higher engagement.

I'm planning to use a hit-scope custom dimension to track the url of the lead image and report on this by template - but I'm not sure how to filter this to landing hits only, or if doing so will be reliable.

Comment: What's your question? Heads up: If you have a large website and use content grouping, you will be subjected to sampling, which might make your data quite inaccurate: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en. I advise use to check the data accuracy by pulling out data on several small date ranges, and comparing it with data pulled over 1 large range covering the same dates to see if data can be trusted.

Comment: The question appears to be how to query content grouping for a landing page. Landing page is session scoped, while content grouping is hit scoped, so it's difficult to combine them into a single query. How can I see what the content grouping of the homepage was? You can query a landing page url, but not a landing page custom dimension. Currently, I need to export this into SQL and run a left-join by URL.

Sampling isn't really relevant to this question, and is simply a general GA comment.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i fully understand what you are asking but if you want to know how can you consume content groping opened by a custom dimension on Google Analytics you need a custom report and you ll need to add a metric too.

[image]

In the image the first column is a custom dimension. The second one is my content groping and i was forced to add a metric too.

Hope it helps.